# EclipseLink auto generates Integer instead of Decimal for H2 database

Tags: database, jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink, h2

Given the following JPA Entity:

```
@Table(name = "T_BOOK")
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = Book.FIND_BY_ISBN_QUERY.QUERY_NAME, query = Book.FIND_BY_ISBN_QUERY.QUERY_STRING)
})
public class Book extends BaseEntity {

    public static class FIND_BY_ISBN_QUERY {
        public static final String QUERY_NAME = "Book.findByISBN";
        public static final String QUERY_STRING = "select new ch.bfh.eadj.dto.BookInfo(b.isbn, b.authors, b.title, b.price) from Book b where b.isbn = :isbn";
    }

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String isbn;

    private String authors;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal price;
```

The schema generation creates the following create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE T_BOOK (NR BIGINT IDENTITY NOT NULL, AUTHORS VARCHAR, BINDING VARCHAR,ISBN VARCHAR NOT NULL, PRICE NUMERIC(38) NOT NULL, TITLE VARCHAR NOT NULL, VERSION INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (NR))
```

So the price field looks like this: `PRICE NUMERIC(38) NOT NULL`

Why does `EclipseLink` create a non-decimal nummeric value?

As soon as I add `@Column(precision = 8, scale = 2)` to the `price` field, it works as expected and creates `PRICE NUMERIC(8,2) NOT NULL` .

Are the `precision` and `scale` attributes on `BigDecimal` columns required when auto generating a schema?

Comment: H2 creates what it is told to create by the JPA provider. Wonder which one you are using

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Added the provider to the question. It's `EclipseLink`

Comment: By default, the EclipseLink persistence provider automatically configures a basic mapping for simple types. If you use annotations like: `@Column`, `@Basic`, etc., you can fine-tune your mappings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that according to the JDBC Specification BigDecimal maps to numeric.
Without specifying the scale the default scale is 0.

NUMERIC(38) (or in databases like oracle NUMBER(38)) is the max value for this data type in the database:

```
38 significant digits in the range of -(10**125) to +(10**125).
```